# How do I POST data via RestTemplate when the returned data contains a Timestamp?

Tags: json, junit, timestamp, resttemplate

I have been struggling with this for hours now. I have a complex class called Location with numerous non-primitive members in it. There are only three non-nullable members, so in a JUnit test I send this Json in a POST to create the class:

```
{ 
    "verified": true,
    "company": "http://localhost:8080/enums_servicingcompany/PBTI",
    "txCode": "http://localhost:8080/enums_tax/9"
}
```

The code to send this and get the response is:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>( locSend, headers ); 
    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(TestBase.URL + URL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    String result= response.getBody();
    HttpHeaders rheaders = response.getHeaders();
```

The response comes back with an 'Okay HTTP200', but result contains:

```
 {"error":"Can not deserialize value of type java.sql.Timestamp from String \"2017-02-06 15:07:17.566\": not a valid representation 
 (error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-02-06 15:07:17.566': Can not parse date \"2017-02-06 15:07:17.566Z\": 
 while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:Ss.SSS'Z'', parsing fails (leniency? null))\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@290d9d75; line: 1, column: 109]
 (through reference chain: mysite.location.Location[\"availableServicesAsOf\"])"}
```

The date/time string it complains about seems to come from the SQL Server database, where that particular column is modified here:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Location_AvailableServicesAsOf]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [AvailableServicesAsOf]
```

Server-side, the Java code for Location includes:

```
@Column(name="AvailableServicesAsOf", nullable=true)    
private java.sql.Timestamp availableServicesAsOf = new java.sql.Timestamp(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
```

The server-side is architected as JPARepository, so all POST processing is done under the covers. The return from the POST, or from a GET, starts off:

```
{
 "creationDate" : null,
 "lastModified" : null,
 "specialhandlingComment" : null,
 "availableServicesAsOf" : "2017-02-06T14:39:52.045+0000",
 "verified" : true,
```

I had started with restTemplate.postForObject(), which works for other classes, but it just gave a 'unable to convert to desired object' because we expected Json and were getting an error message - which didn't help in the slightest.

So what I can do to solve this issue? Without being able to POST data, I can't create instances for doing JUnit testing. (Everything works when requests come in from the front end.)

Surprisingly, I can execute the following JUnit code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
    FMT_Location_RCV location = restTemplate.getForObject(TestBase.URL + URL + id, FMT_Location_RCV.class);
```

and I receive the data from Location with no errors. avaialableServicesAsOf contains the String "2017-02-06T21:48:52.285+0000". So why does it format successfully on a GET, but if I try the postForObject() with the same formatted Java class, it fails?